# Android SQLite - what does SQLiteDatabase.replace() actually do?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need to do a INSERT or UPDATE IF EXIST type of procedure with my database. I read that `.replace()` was the way to go. It inserts new records just fine, but if the record already exists, it doesn't appear to update it.

I have something like this:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(ID, 1);
values.put(NAME, "bob");
values.put(VISIBLE, true);
db.replace("peopleTable", null, values);
```

If I run this code when this record isn't in the database, it appears to create the record just fine, as if I did an `insert()`. But if I change NAME to "john" or something like that, and run the `replace()` again, it doesn't appear to update the record.

According to the docs, here is the syntax:

```
public long replace (String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues initialValues)
```

Why is it called `initalValues`? Does that mean those values are only used when the record doesn't exist and it's going to be inserted? If so, how do you use the method to update a record? Where do you specify the new values?

If I am misunderstanding what `replace()` does altogether, can someone explain what it's purpose is?

Comment: You can use both the `INSERT` and `REPLACE` procedures in your `ContentProvider.insert()` methods if you pass a special parameter in your `ContentValues`. I wrote a blog post about it here: [SQLite INSERT OR REPLACE through ContentProvider | Buzzing Android](http://www.buzzingandroid.com/2013/01/sqlite-insert-or-replace-through-contentprovider/)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As I understand it `replace()` works much like the SQLite [REPLACE](http://sqlite.org/lang_replace.html) keyword - a row will be updated if a unique constraint violation occurs for the insert. So the ID column in your example would need to have a PRIMARY KEY constraint in the database schema for the row to be updated.

Comment: I think that might be the problem.

Comment: First of all, yes the "_id" field is the PRIMARY KEY. Second, new records are not being created. This means that the method is in fact finding the original record and not making a new one. But like I said, the existing record just isn't getting updated...

Comment: Yeah, to quote @JesperB's blog post - "As you can see in the official documentation (SQL As Understood By SQLite), the command does an INSERT OR REPLACE. That is, do an INSERT, and if that INSERT fails because of a conflict, delete the conflicting rows before INSERTing again."

Answer (score 5):

The replace() method actually execute the sql command `insert or replace into (...) values (...)`

Answer (score 0):

The **update()** work in my case:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = taskHelper.getWritableDatabase();
String DBroll =TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE;
String taskU = String.valueOf(taskEdit.getText()); 
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(DBroll, taskU); 
db.update(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE, values, DBroll + " = ?", new String[]{taskD});
db.close();
```